# NG8001: 'some-component' is not a known element - angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-publish, ng-packagr

I use angular 13.3. I have a project that name is "pazh-base-source" that some of my base component is in it such as pazh-component.ts . I want to use this components in my main project. I export the pazh-component in app module in pazh-base-source, also I set the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in schemas in app-module of my both project (main and pazh-base-source). I use `"ng-packagr -p ng-package.json && cd dist && npm publish"` to publish pazh-base-source and then use `npm i pazh-base-source` and import it in my app-module in main project but when I use `"ng-packagr -p ng-package.json && cd dist && npm publish"` in main project to publish it, I get this error:
error image: [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kwCo.png), error code:

```
src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'pazh-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'pazh-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pazh-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

my app.component.ts of main source:

```
<pazh-component>
   <p>test</p>
</pazh-component>
```

my app.module.ts of main source:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PazhComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
```

my pazh-component.module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PazhComponentComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    PazhComponentComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  ],
  providers: [
    PazhFormBuilderService,
    ReferralService
  ],
})
```

I also check the selectors and [other way that angular.io](https://angular.io/errors/NG8001#debugging-the-error) said.

Comment: Is `pazh-component` exported by `PazhComponentsModule` ? (Likely not)

Comment: yes I export it in base-source

Comment: Can you also add PazhComponentsModule code for this question